# When using isupper and islower

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, passwords

I am trying to make a password strength checker and I have run into a problem, I know the solution, but don't know the code for it though.

Here is the code

```
if password.isupper :
  print (50 * '-')
  print ("consider using UPPERCASE and lowercase letters")
  print (50 * '-')
if password.islower :
  print (50 * '-')
  print ("consider using UPPERCASE and lowercase letters")
  print (50 * '-')
```

So is there a way that it will only print "consider using UPPERCASE and lowercase letters" when the WHOLE password is lowercase or uppercase, not mixed.

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: You are not calling the method. missing `()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need to put these two conditions into one if you don't need to consider other characters such as numbers:

```
if password.isupper() or password.islower():
    print (50 * '-')
    print ("consider using UPPERCASE and lowercase letters")
    print (50 * '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `password.isupper()` not `password.isupper`

e.g.

```
password='TT'
if password.isupper() :
  print (50 * '-')
  print ("consider using lowercase letters")

elif password.islower() :
  print (50 * '-')
  print ("consider using UPPERCASE letters")

else:
    print("good password")
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if an a password is entirely uppercase or entirely lowercase:

```
if password.isupper() or password.islower():
    print ("consider using UPPERCASE and lowercase letters")
```

Comment: What is wrong with using `isupper()` or `islower()`?

Comment: Updated my response.

Comment: The `not`s within the parentheses are unnecessary. An equivalent statement can be formed without them by changing `and` to `or`, which more clearly captures the intent.

Comment: Oh, thanks.  I accepted the edit.